# Почему текст всех исключения на русском языке?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio

Сама студия английская. А текст, которые кидаются исключениями русский. Очень не удобно. Подскажите из-за чего и как сделать английский?

Comment: переключить винду на английский.

Comment: Хм, это у них нововведение что ли... Помню, когда было VS2008, такой ерунды не было.

Comment: Студия тут ни при чем. Это зависит от локали

Comment: `\#if DEBUG
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");    
\#endif`